# Isn't this the most compact binary representation of all numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, information-theory, binary

Here is the transformation:
$$\begin{align*}
&1\to(0)\\
&2\to(1)\\
&3\to(10)\\
&4\to((1))\\
&5\to(100)\\
&6\to(11)\\
&7\to(1000)\\
&8\to((10))\\
&9\to((1)0)\\
&10\to(101)\\
&11\to(10000)\\
&12\to(1(1))\\
&13\to(100000)\\
&14\to(1001)\\
&15\to(110)\\
&16\to(((1)))\\
&17\to(1000000)\\
&18\to((1)1)\\
&19\to(10000000)\\
\end{align*}$$
and so on
...
The idea is to use $i_{th}$ position to represent the power of $i_{th}$ prime denominator. There is a recursive hierarchy whit parenthesis indicating beginning and end of each number. Since primes are building blocks of all numbers, this representation must have maximum information and minimum number of digits compared to all and every other binary representation.

1. Can you prove me right or wrong?
2. Is this being already used?

P.S. "Assuming that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are two uniquely decodable codes of natural numbers, $\psi$ is more compact than $\phi$ if the average number of digits that you use with $\psi$ to represent N natural numbers randomly chosen between 1 and M where (M>N) and N→∞ is less than that of $\phi$."

Comment: You use four symbols. How is this binary, then?

Comment: It can be reduced to 3 symbols

Comment: @MajidFekri In what sense would mapping $101$ to $(10000000000000000000000)$ rather than $1100101$ qualify as compact?

Comment: $3 > 2\mbox{}\mbox{}$

Comment: @ErickWong Think about all numbers with equal probability of appearance, where primes are rare.

Comment: $2^n$ gets mapped to $$\underbrace{((\ldots((}_{n-1}2\underbrace{))\ldots))}_{n-1}\;,$$ which requires $2n-1$ symbols rather than the $n+1$ required in binary.

Comment: @Majid: There is no probability distribution on $\Bbb Z^+$ that makes each integer equally likely.

Comment: This representation has restrictions on the sequence in which symbols can appear. For example, parentheses must be balanced. It cannot possibly represent as many different numbers in $N$ digits as a simple base-three system can (which allows _all_ $N$-digit sequences of $\{0,1,2\}$ in an $N$-digit number).

Comment: @DavidK, good point but "on average" prime presentation would still use less than N digits.

Comment: Base-three can represent $3^N$ different numbers in $N$ digits or fewer. A three-symbol version of your representation cannot. Fewer numbers in the same number of digits implies more digits per number. One has only to look at your first nineteen examples (none of which would require more than five binary digits!) to see how verbose it is.

Comment: @DavidK It is because prime numbers happen to be dense at the beginning, you should consider all numbers.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott. No. That is wrong. $2^2^2^...$ maps to $((..(1)..))$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $N$ large.  Then the number of integers in $[1,N]$ which have a prime factor greater than $\sqrt N$ is asymptotic to $N \log 2$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickman_function).  These numbers all require at least $\pi(\sqrt{N}) \sim 2 \sqrt{N}/\log N$ bits.  Therefore the average number of bits used will be asymptotically at least as high as $(2\log 2) \sqrt{N} / \log N$.  This is grossly inefficient on average, compared to the $\log N / \log 2 + O(1)$ bits that the standard binary representation uses.

Update: actually, the contribution from the primes by themselves is already large enough to upset the average.  The total number of bits consumed by the $\approx N/\log N$ primes is about $\tfrac12 (N/\log N)^2$, so the average bit usage coming from just the primes is asymptotic to $N/(2\log^2 N)$.  It's unrealistic to expect such a wildly irregular encoding which has exponentially-bad worst case to beat the greedy binary encoding on average.

Answer (score 7):

Primes are rare, but numbers with large prime factors are common. If $n$ is around $2^{100}$, it will take about 100 bits to represent it in the usual base-2 way. It will take more than 100 bits to represent it your way, if it is divisible by any prime exceeding the 100th prime, and most numbers in the neighborhood of $2^{100}$ are divisible by some prime exceeding the 100th prime. However you choose to define "on average", on average your representation loses out to ordinary base-2.

Comment: @Majid: What an amazingly common mistake: each individual large prime is rarely a factor, but there are a whole lot of them.

Comment: That's true. On the other hand we can represent numbers as large as 541!(~3.e1245) with only about a hundred digits, while it would require about 4000 binary digits.

Comment: @MajidFekri Numbers whose prime factors are as small as they are for factorials are much, much rarer than the primes.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by *a binary representation of all numbers* and by *most compact*. One interpretation is a mapping $\varphi$ from the *natural* numbers to binary strings such that given a binary string encoding possibly more than one number, there is at most one way of decoding it. For example, suppose we encode the numbers $0,1,2,3,\ldots$ using the binary strings $1,01,001,0001,\ldots$. Then $0101001$ can be decoded as $1,1,2$, and $010$ has no decoding at all; but no string is ambiguous (has more than one decoding). Such a mapping $\varphi$ is known as a *uniquely decodable code of the natural numbers*.

Defining *most compact* is slightly more complicated. For example, suppose that we replace $1,01,001,0001,\ldots$ by $01,1,001,0001,\ldots$; which is more compact? And among $1,01,001,0001,00001,000001,0000001,\ldots$ and $1,010,011,00100,00101,00110,00111,\ldots$, which is more compact? The former encodes $n$ using $n+1$ bits, the latter using roughly $2\log n$ bits. One possible definition is the following:

> Suppose $\varphi,\psi$ are two uniquely decodable codes of the natural numbers whose codeword lengths are non-decreasing (so $|\varphi(0)| \leq |\varphi(1)| \leq |\varphi(2)| \leq \cdots$). We say that $\psi$ is *more compact* than $\varphi$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} |\psi(n)|-|\varphi(n)| = -\infty$.

In other words, $\psi$ is more compact than $\varphi$ if for every $C$, large codewords of $\psi$ are shorter by at least $C$ than their counterparts in $\varphi$. For example, the code $1,010,011,\ldots$ is more compact than the code $1,01,001,\ldots$ under this definition.

Under these definitions, it is not too difficult to show that there is *no* most compact code (see for example [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.1600), though one can come up with simpler proofs). In other words, given a uniquely decodable code of the natural numbers $\varphi$, one can construct another uniquely decodable code of the natural numbers $\psi$ which is more compact than $\varphi$.

In fact, the situation is much worse: given any *sequence* $\varphi_1,\varphi_2,\ldots$ of codes, one can construct a code $\psi$ which is more compact than all of them at the same time! If you allow uncountable "sequences", then the existence of a *scale* of codes becomes independent of ZFC, just like the Continuum Hypothesis.

Comment: First, of course it is a uniquely decodable code of natural numbers. Second, no this is not what I mean by compactness. Your definition obviously doesn't lead to a unique sequence. What I have in mind as a measure of compactness is the average number of digits that you use to represent N natural numbers randomly chosen between 1 and M where (M>N) and N→∞

Comment: You haven't explained when a given code is more compact than another. Once you do, I bet that you will find out that either there is no "most compact" code, or that there are many "most compact" codes, depending on your definition. In the latter case you may or may not be happy with the conclusion.

Comment: I think I just did. The non-decreasing rule doesn't apply to this representation. It is more non-linear than usual sequences. My point is that it is optimum on average.

Comment: You haven't explained when a code $\psi$ is more compact than a code $\varphi$. In order to answer your question we need a *definition* of "more compact". Such a definition has the form "$\psi$ is more compact than $\varphi$ if ______".

Comment: Let's say "ψ  is more compact than φ  if the average number of digits that you use with ψ to represent N natural numbers randomly chosen between 1 and M where (M>N) and N→∞ is less than that of φ".

Comment: What role does the $N$ play in this definition?  How does it give a different average than taking $N=M$?

Comment: Your definition depends on $M$, and given $M$, only depends on a finite part of the code, so in this case there is a most compact representation, since it's a finite problem. But is that really what you want?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The definition seems muddled, but it's hard to interpret it as prescribing a fixed $M$ when $M>N$ and $N\to \infty$ :)