# Confusion about Kraft-McMillan inequality for infinite alphabet

Tags: information-theory, cryptography

I was wondering if the Kraft-McMillan inequality continues to hold for codes with infinite alphabets. The reason I'm confused about this is because I was thinking about a code from $\{0,1\}^*$ to $\{0,1\}^*$ (all strings consisting of 0's and 1's of all possible lengths), which simply maps each string to itself. This is obviously a uniquely decodable code. However, it satisfies
\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{x \in \{0,1\}^*} 2^{-\ell(x)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^k 2^{-k} = \infty,
\end{equation}
since there are $2^k$ codewords of length $k$.
So the Kraft-McMillan inequality does not hold.
Is there an additional condition that needs to be satisfied in order for the inequality to hold for infinite alphabets?
Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: The inequality only applies to uniquely decodable codes, and the code you've described is not uniquely decodable (is the string $00$ composed of two $0$s, or one $00$?). As for whether the inequality applies to infinite alphabet uniquely decodable codes: yes. Indeed, it holds for every finite subcode, and you can take a limit to conclude for the full code.

Comment: Then does there exist any uniquely decodable code from $\{0,1\}^*$ to $\{0,1\}^*$? I don't think so right?

Comment: $\{0,1\}^*$ is countable, so we can map it to the naturals. And then the unary code from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}^*$ exists ($n\mapsto 1^n 0$), so we can compose these (let $\nu: \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$ be a fixed bijection. Then go $x \to \nu(x) \to 1^{\nu(x)}0$). This is u.d. because each $0$ tells us when the code for the symbol terminates, at which point we can figure out $\nu(x_i)$ and invert it.

Comment: Oh amazing, thanks! :)

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4407414/the-kraft-and-mcmillan-inequalities-for-infinite-codes https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047800/312